# How to install bootloader on usb-stick after failure?

Tags: live-usb

When you write iso to usb-stick in the end it asks you password in order to install bootloader. But if you enter wrong password (it seems 2 times) or leave computer for some time then writing process stops. How can I install bootloader after this failure.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using the "Startup Disc Creator".  Try using unetbootin instead, it's in the repositories.  If it asks you about overwriting a file just click "Yes to All".  I've historically had more luck out of Unetbootin than the "Startup Disc Creator".

Comment: Thanks, but it is not an answer to the question, it is more for comments.